# ServerError 500 on updating mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, server-error

So the problem with this is, i want to create whenever a user presses login a value in the database changes to 1, but whenever i use UPDATE we get a servererror 500 at the click of login

```
<?php
require("inc/db.php");
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $errMsg = '';
  //username and password sent from Form
  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  if($username == '')
    $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

  if($password == '')
    $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


  if($errMsg == ''){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password,email,bday,points,uid FROM  users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
    $records->bindParam(':username', $username) ;
    $records->bindParam(':password', $password) ;
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($results > 0){

      $sql = "UPDATE users SET isloggedin = :isloggedin WHERE username = :username";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':isloggedin', '1');
      $stmt->execute();


      $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
      $_SESSION['id'] = $results['id'];
      $_SESSION['points'] = $results['points'];
      $_SESSION['uid'] = $results['uid'];





      header('location:dashboard.php');
    }else{
      $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

So, the UPDATE function is not working properly, me and my friend cant find the solution to this, we tried to work around it, or tried to change lines for it, but nothing worked...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use PDO, but my guess is that you need to bind the :username parameter in each query. The server 500 error makes me thing you're running this as CGI perhaps?

Comment: How are you calling this routine? Ajax? Error 500 usually means that either there is a PHP syntax error or the posted data it expects is not being passed correctly.

Comment: I notice that you have no `bindParam(':username', $username)`, so I suspect PDO is throwing an exception due to an inconsistency between the number of params in the SQL statement and the params actually available at `execute()`.

Comment: There is nothing being showed, When i put the errorreporting and display errors on the site cant even get to the login.php but shows a 500 error immediatly. The error comes when i click on LOGIN

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski       $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username); i added that, still error 500

Comment: Per my earlier comment, you must check your error log or set display_errors. The full details of the 500 will be shown. You are actively preventing them now at the top. Use `E_ALL` for `error_reporting()` and `1` for `display_errors`.

Comment: Got the error now: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\Websites\GingeDevil\login.php on line 33 :       $stmt->bindParam(':isloggedin', '1');

Comment: Looks like a wrong type.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That makes me feel so stupid, But again thanks ! it works! :D

Comment: I'll summarize them as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues, which will surface one at a time once error reporting is turned up. Always when developing and testing code, set `error_reporting` all the way up to `E_ALL` and enable display errors with `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.  Those together will detail the 500 error on screen for you, making it much more obvious right away.

The first issue I spotted is that your `UPDATE` statement has two parameters `:isloggedin, :username` but only the first of them is bound with `bindParam()`. You must also bind the second, as PDO is throwing an exception related to an invalid parameter number.

```
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET isloggedin = :isloggedin WHERE username = :username";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':isloggedin', '1');
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
```

But that only gets you partway there. PDO will next error due to the use of the static string value `'1'` in `bindParam()`, which only accepts variables as its second argument (because it utilizes them by reference). The alternative is to use `bindValue()` to pass a static value. Since you are not executing the same statement many times with changing variable values, it is also then safe to bind `:username` with `bindValue()`, though that one would work either way for your case.

```
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET isloggedin = :isloggedin WHERE username = :username";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  // Make sure static values are bound by value
  $stmt->bindValue(':isloggedin', '1');
  $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
```